# Fortran Makefile - Circular dependency dropped and m2c

Tags: makefile, fortran

The following is a working make; it is a simplified version of a more complex one, but it manages to reproduce the problems when I try some changes. Files "myobj.f" and "mymod.f" are in folders "src1" and "src2" respectively and are almost empty (mymod is a module that has a variable declared and myobj is a subroutine that initializes and prints that variable).

I tried googling for this, but all circular dependency errors I found seemed more clear than this. Could you please help me identify what is wrong with my makefile?

```
all : mylib.so
makefiles := Makefile
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -I$(obj_path) -J$(obj_path) -fPIC
LFLAGS = -shared -fPIC

obj_path := obj
src_paths = src1 src2
vpath %.o   $(obj_path)
vpath %.mod $(obj_path)
vpath %.f   $(src_paths)

objects = myobj.o mymod.o
obj/myobj.o : obj/mymod.mod

mylib.so : $(objects:%.o=$(obj_path)/%.o)
        $(FC) $(LFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

$(obj_path)/%.mod : %.o
        @touch $@

$(obj_path)/%.o   : %.f   $(makefiles) |  $(obj_path)
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(obj_path) :
        mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf mylib.so $(obj_path)
```

#### (1) I can't simplify the rules

Having the "$(obj_path)" explicitly in the rules for compiling objects seems unnecessary: I know vpath does not work with files that change during compile time and was designed only for sources, but I don't see why clarifying the path when I list the objects as dependencies of the library shouldn't suffice.

```
mylib.so : $(objects:%.o=$(obj_path)/%.o)
        $(FC) $(LFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

%.mod : %.o
        @touch $@

%.o   : %.f   $(makefiles) |  $(obj_path)
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

But this doesn't work; I get a circular dependency dropped warning and make tries to compile the modules using m2c. Just in case, commenting the vpaths for .o and .mod does not fix this. Output of make --debug:

```
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
   File 'mylib.so' does not exist.
     File 'obj/myobj.o' does not exist.
make: Circular obj/myobj.mod <- obj/myobj.o dependency dropped.
       File 'obj/mymod.mod' does not exist.
         File 'obj/mymod.o' does not exist.
make: Circular obj/mymod.o <- obj/mymod.mod dependency dropped.
        Must remake target 'obj/mymod.o'.
m2c    -o obj/mymod.o 
make: m2c: Command not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'obj/mymod.o' failed
make: *** [obj/mymod.o] Error 127
```

#### (2) I can't add a rule for f90

Now I want to be able to incorporate f90 code to my library. Adding the rule seems not to affect the process if nothing else changes, but when I change the extension of mymod.f to mymod.f90, it returns a similar error that the other case. The modified section is:

```
$(obj_path)/%.mod : %.o
        @touch $@

$(obj_path)/%.o   : %.f   $(makefiles) |  $(obj_path)
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(obj_path)/%.o   : %.f90   $(makefiles) |  $(obj_path)
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

And the output of make --debug is this:

```
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
   File 'mylib.so' does not exist.
     File 'obj/myobj.o' does not exist.
       File 'obj' does not exist.
      Must remake target 'obj'.
mkdir -p obj
      Successfully remade target file 'obj'.
       File 'obj/mymod.mod' does not exist.
         File 'obj/mymod.o' does not exist.
make: Circular obj/mymod.o <- obj/mymod.mod dependency dropped.
        Must remake target 'obj/mymod.o'.
m2c    -o obj/mymod.o 
make: m2c: Command not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'obj/mymod.o' failed
make: *** [obj/mymod.o] Error 127
```

---

#### COMPILATION CONFIG 1:

Makefile:

```
all : mylib.so
makefiles := Makefile
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -I$(obj_path) -J$(obj_path) -fPIC
LFLAGS = -shared -fPIC

obj_path := obj
src_paths = src1 src2
#vpath %.o   $(obj_path)
#vpath %.mod $(obj_path)
vpath %.f   $(src_paths)

objects = myobj.o mymod.o
obj/myobj.o : obj/mymod.mod

mylib.so : $(objects:%.o=$(obj_path)/%.o)
        $(FC) $(LFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

%.mod : %.o
        @touch $@

%.o   : %.f   $(makefiles) |  $(obj_path)
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(obj_path) :
        mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf mylib.so $(obj_path)
```

src1/myobj.f:

```
       subroutine myobj
       use mymod
       implicit none
       mymodx=1
       print*,'mymod was included', mymodx
       return
       end subroutine
```

src2/mymod.f:

```
       module mymod
       implicit none
       integer :: mymodx
       end module
```

Terminal output:

```
make --debug
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
   File 'mylib.so' does not exist.
     File 'obj/myobj.o' does not exist.
make: Circular obj/myobj.mod <- obj/myobj.o dependency dropped.
       File 'obj/mymod.mod' does not exist.
         File 'obj/mymod.o' does not exist.
make: Circular obj/mymod.o <- obj/mymod.mod dependency dropped.
        Must remake target 'obj/mymod.o'.
m2c    -o obj/mymod.o 
make: m2c: Command not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'obj/mymod.o' failed
make: *** [obj/mymod.o] Error 127
```

Comment: You get the `.mod -> .o`/`.o -> .mod` circular dependency *without* the `vpath` lines? I don't see how that would be happening. What version of make is this? I don't get this output here (with just `Makefile`, `src1/myobj.f` and `src2/mymod.f` files).

Comment: I am using Make 4.1. In the first case I do. In the second case I just tried commenting the vpath lines and now I'm getting this other error instead: `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/mymod.mod', needed by 'obj/myobj.o'.  Stop.`. Note: when I comment the `vpath`lines in the original makefile, I get an additional line at compiling that says `gfortran -Iobj -Jobj -fPIC  -c -o mymod.o src2/mymod.f`, before the other three (which include compiling again the mod with my rule: `gfortran -Iobj -Jobj -fPIC -c src2/mymod.f -o obj/mymod.o`).

Comment: Can you update the post with the exact makefiles and the exact output from the different attempts? Without the `vpath` lines I get that no rule issue but I don't see the circular issue with them with make 4.1 (and exactly the files, empty source files, I listed before).

Comment: Ok, I'll update now. Two comments though: (1) what do you mean by empty? Mine are not completely empty, they do have the declaration and use statement. I will include them in my description. (2) I am sshing from OSX into a linuxbox; I have exported LANG=C and LC_ALL=C, which used to cause problems before, but didn't find anything suggesting my current problem may also be related to this.

Comment: I mean in my test the files are empty (it shouldn't matter I was just mentioning it).

Comment: Just updated it. Do you want me to add the error logs with the second part as well? with or without vpath? (in the second part I get a different error depending on which)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your approach.  The `vpath` searching only applies to pre-requisites and not targets, so a rule like

```
%.o: %.f
```

will search the `$(src_paths)` for the source but it will not attempt to match targets in `$(obj_path)`.  This leads to the next issue, that due to putting objects into an intermediate directory, your rule needs to account for this since `vpath` won't help.  Your main target to build the library depends on things like `$(obj_path)/blah.f` so you want to use a rule like:

```
$(obj_path)/%.o: %.f
```

to match the objects.   There may be a cleaner way to do this, but I am not aware of them.

Likewise, the rule with the `%.mod` target was not matching the requirement in the object directory and it looks like a default implicit rule was being called to handle them, attempting to invoke `m2c`.
Specifically, make tries to compile the mod file as modula-2 source and its automatic rule to do this conflicted with your `%.o:%.mod` rule and produced the circular dependency.
By modifying that rule to properly match the mod files, this mess is avoided.

Also, dont forget to add a `vpath` for `%.f90`, so your rules can find those source files.

I can successfully build your test project with this slightly modified Makefile.  I also used files named `.f90` to show that it also solves your second issue.

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -I$(obj_path) -J$(obj_path) -fPIC
LFLAGS = -shared -fPIC

src_paths = src1 src2
obj_path := obj
vpath %.o $(obj_path)
vpath %.mod $(obj_path)
vpath %.f90 $(src_paths)
vpath %.f $(src_paths)

mylib_objects = myobj.o mymod.o
mylib_target = mylib.so

all: $(mylib_target)

$(mylib_target) : $(mylib_objects:%.o=$(obj_path)/%.o)
    $(FC) $(LFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

$(obj_path)/myobj.o: myobj.f90 $(obj_path)/mymod.mod

$(obj_path) :
    mkdir -p $@

$(obj_path)/%.mod : %.o $(obj_path)
    @true

$(obj_path)/%.o: %.f | $(obj_path)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(obj_path)/%.o: %.f90 | $(obj_path)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(mylib_target) $(obj_path)
```

From a clean start, the output of `make --debug` is:

```
% make --debug
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
   File 'mylib.so' does not exist.
     File 'obj/myobj.o' does not exist.
       File 'obj' does not exist.
      Must remake target 'obj'.
mkdir -p obj
      Successfully remade target file 'obj'.
       File 'obj/mymod.mod' does not exist.
         File 'obj/mymod.o' does not exist.
        Must remake target 'obj/mymod.o'.
gfortran -Iobj -Jobj -fPIC -c src2/mymod.f90 -o obj/mymod.o
        Successfully remade target file 'obj/mymod.o'.
      Must remake target 'obj/mymod.mod'.
      Successfully remade target file 'obj/mymod.mod'.
    Must remake target 'obj/myobj.o'.
gfortran -Iobj -Jobj -fPIC -c src1/myobj.f90 -o obj/myobj.o
    Successfully remade target file 'obj/myobj.o'.
  Must remake target 'mylib.so'.
gfortran -shared -fPIC obj/myobj.o obj/mymod.o  -o mylib.so
  Successfully remade target file 'mylib.so'.
Must remake target 'all'.
Successfully remade target file 'all'.
```

---

Also note that you can instead handle your module dependency by stipulating the object files in an other that guarantees necessary mod files will have been generated.  For example, changing

```
objects = myobj.o mymod.o
```

to

```
objects = mymod.o myobj.o
```

makes the rules and pre-requisites involving the mod files un-necessary, as this will cause `mymod.o` (and the byproduct `mymod.mod`) to be built before `myobj.o` is attempted.  It is possible that this solution would break in a parallel build, so I have maintained your object ordering and made sure the rules worked as intended.

Comment: What modifications did you make and why/how do they fix the problem? Could you reproduce the original problem(s)?

Comment: @EtanReisner was right, I should have copied the whole Makefile: I wasn't vpathing the .F90!! I am so silly, apologies for that miss. Ok, this fixed my second problem; the make now works fine when adding the f90, which was the most important part, but I still don't know why its necessary to add the `$(obj_path)/` in the rules for the objects.

Comment: @Nordico the vpath only does things to the prerequisite, not the target. If you want to avoid the `$(obj_path)/` in the rules you could put a Makefile in `obj` that compiles the objects and call that Makefile from the main one that builds the library.  There are a few ways to do it, but I tried to stay as close to your attempt as possible and this is what I got to work.

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem now; my confusion was not exactly with vpath, and I just figured it out by trying to explain here why it wasn't about vpath, heh. Replacement in my first rule has `mylib.so` depend on `/obj/myobj.o`, and if the rule only says `%.o : %.f`, then it looks for `/obj/myobj.f`, which obviously never finds even when it looks in the vpath because the sources are not under an `obj` directory. When the rule is written `$(obj_src)/%.o : %.f` then it searches for `myobj.f` (because "%" only contains the name of the file now) and has no problem finding it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @casey Selected your reply as the answer because even though does not explicitly answer the questions, together with the comments it contains everything necessary to figure it out. Thanks again. Should I add/edit something in my question to make things clearer or do I leave it as is?

Comment: If this isn't a correct solution but it led you to the correct solution then I would either request this be updated to the correct solution (or edit it yourself) or write up your own answer (crediting this one) that contains the correct solution and accept that one.

Comment: @Nordico see if my edit hit all your points.  You can feel free to suggest an edit to anything you think is worthwhile and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I think the addition of the `/obj/myobj.f` part in the post was enough for this to qualify. You could add something along the lines of "Did you remember to include .f90 in your vpath?", but since my first comment points to this I might be unnecessary. Don't really have much of a criteria for this and I feel like most other comments would be too subjective (like the focus on how vpath doesn't affect targets, that I think is not the issue here, but I guess that is a matter of perspective, and it may be useful for general reference or as a clarification).